Time Cost for Webflux WebCient
I have a spring boot service which calls another external service using WebClient. Average Latency of the external service is around 15 ms (Measured through Datadog). But when the external API is called through our service, the average time taken for the external API call with webClient is much higher than this value where it comes around 65 ms.
This is a sample code for how external API is called.
public Foo fetchFoo() {
    return webClient.get()
        .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
            .path(externalAPIEndPoint)
            .build())
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Foo.class)
        .retry(defaultMaxRetry)
        .block();
}

What could be the reason for this huge time difference? What are the approaches we can take to to reduce the time taken?

There are many reasons why there could be delays. In example :
Reasons for latency:

You are using the method  .block(); it could lead to delays, you could just remove it and keep retry.

The call to the externalAPIEndpoint could have network latency, by creating new connection, or maybe because of handshake/TLS check. This could be maybe improved by using connection pool.

retry() method can also cause delay, because usually with retry there are important parameters, like retry delay and number of retries. So optimizing your retry policy (depending on the need), could also help reduce latency.


Improvement i would suggest :

Take advance of connection pools, something like :

Code example :
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create(ConnectionProvider.builder("custom")
    .maxConnections(100)
    .build());
WebClient client = WebClient.builder()
    .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
    .build();


remove block() method, your code becomes :

code example
public Mono<Foo> fetchFoo() {
    return webClient.get()
        .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(externalAPIEndPoint).build())
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Foo.class)
        .retry(defaultMaxRetry);
}


In order to have better idea about the latency, you should check the health and metrics, based on which you can have better understanding on what to improve exactly.

Extras (they may be out of scope of this post, but maybe worth mentioning):

You could also add caching policy, to improve performance, in case you have high load traffic.

You can also add auto-scaling based on specific metrics.


